# return non-duplication of records in result with linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

How i can return non-duplication of records in result with linq?

```
var design = firoozehDataContext.Designs;
comboBoxCode.DataSource = design.ToList();
```

above code return all records, but i want to do that i said on above.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx).

Like `var design = firoozehDataContext.Designs.Distinct();`